# Mixing SATA speed on hardware RAID

Tags: raid, sata

I have a 16 drive hardware RAID array which has 15/16 3 Gb/S SATA drives. On replacing a failing drive I realized the replacement was a 6 GB/S drive (same brand/cache,size though).

Is this likely to cause issues down the road - if I'd realized beforehand I wouldn't have tried, but the RAID array is rebuilding fine (which is good!).

I just don't want an issue where under high load this causes problems. My guess would be everything ends up being bottlenecked by the lowest speed connection, so the 6 Gb/s SATA will end up acting like a 3 Gb/s SATA anyway.

Edit - specific models:

```
RAID controller - 3ware 9650SE-16ML RAID

Disks
Western Digital 500 GB - WD RE WD5003ABYX # 3 Gb/S (15/16 of the drives)
Western Digital 500 GB - WD RE WD5003ABYZ # 6 Gb/S (1/16 of the drives)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brands and specific models of the equipment involved are ALWAYS appreciated.

However, you'll be fine. The SATA 3.0 protocol is backward compatible with previous generations. The drives will link at their respective disk/backplane speeds.

Comment: Cool - thanks. That's what I would have guessed, but I suppose it's nice to have an actual in-production example of it being true and not corrupting everything!